# Replace a clustered index with a non-clustered one on primary key using SQL Server Management Studio UI without generating a script

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When you designate a column as the primary key in SQL Server Management Studio, it automatically creates a clustered index on the column. How do you replace the index with a non-clustered one using the SQL Server Management Studio user interface, but without generating or writing a script to drop the index and create the non-clustered one?

I know how to do it with a script (`ALTER TABLE` and then `DROP CONSTRAINT`), whether hand-written or generated using Management Studio. I am asking how to do it using only the Management Studio user interface. Because I remember I did it in the past. Only, I've forgotten how to do it because it has been a few months now.

I am using SQL Server Management Studio v17.9.1.

Comment: A primary key will *always* have an index related to it. It doesn't, however, have to be a `CLUSTERED` index. The type of index (`CLUSTERED`/`NONCLUSTERED`) depends on the way you declare the Primary key (or lack of declaring it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, with some more poking around, I found out what I had done earlier. This is the way.

1. Right-click on the primary key column when it is open in the designer and select the menu command **Indexes/Keys**.
2. Set **Create as Clustered** to the value `No` in the ensuing dialog.

See the pictures below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you did in this answer, you CHANGED PK from clustered to nonclustered. I.e. you did: alter table drop constraint + alter table create constraint PK nonclustered, recreate a costraint is not the same as "drop clustered index"

Comment: @sepupic While I am aware of what I did, I realize now that I did not express my intention clearly in the question. I am updating the question since what I have done is exactly what I was trying to remember.